# How to add Discord user ID to bot embed message when they react with a certain reaction?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I've just picked up python and have done some searching on the internet, discord py API, and StackOverflow, but I'm still not sure how to get my discord bot to work properly.

Is there a way to get the discord user ID's when a user reacts with the checkmark on the bot's embed message?

Here is what my code:
This part works:

```
#new dely ubjectiv
  if msg.startswith('$new_dobj'):
    
    ubj = msg.replace('$new_dobj ','')

    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Dely Ubjectiv:", description = ubj +"\n\n**ppl hoo compleeted it:**", colour = 0x99dfff)
    m = await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    await m.add_reaction('✅')
```

- Code below doesn't seem to do anything. goal: when ppl click the checkmark reaction their
  user id gets added under the 'ppl hoo compleeted it'
  in the message.

  ```
  user_reaction = await client.wait_for('reaction_add')
    u = user_reaction.message.id

    if user_reaction == '✅':
      m = m.append(">>> " + u + "\n")
      await msg.edit(m)
  ```

Here's an image of what it looks like so far in Discord:
[screenshot_of_delyubjectivbot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHNRu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `on_reaction_add` takes two arguments, it returns a tuple. The return values from `client.wait_for` mirror the arguments from the event reference, seen here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord-api-events

This example should give you a good starting point:

```py
reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add')
# Just access `user.id` for the id

if str(reaction.emoji) == '✅':
    e = m.embeds[0]
    e.description = f'{e.description}\n> {user}'
    await m.edit(embed=e)
```

It's unclear what `msg` is meant to be in your code. It looks like a `str`, but you also call `msg.edit`, which only works on a `discord.Message` object.

Update:

```py
async def on_message(m):

    # put your msg content and etc here

    def check(reaction, user):
        return m.id == reaction.message.id and str(reaction.emoji) == '✅'

    description = m.embeds[0].description

    while not client.is_closed():
        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check, timeout=35)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            break
        else:
            e = m.embeds[0]
            description += f'\n> {user.mention}'
            e.description = description
            await m.edit(embed=e)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! I'll try some stuff and see what happens.
`msg` is representing `message.content`, sorry for not clarifying that earlier.

Comment: Currently, the bot only adds the username for the user who called the `$new_dobj` command. 
Here is what I added based on your recommendations:
   `reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add')

    if str(reaction.emoji) == '✅':
      if user == client.user:
        return
      else:
        e = m.embeds[0]
        e.description = f'{e.description}\n> <@{user.id}>'
        await m.edit(embed=e)`

Comment: I've updated the message to include a way to keep the reactions active for 35 seconds at a time, and a `check` function to wait specifically for that kind of reaction instead of waiting for any reaction and checking it afterwards

Comment: Thanks! I figured out how to make the bot add more than one username by using a while loop. I found this here, but they were trying to make an event scheduling bot. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68506416/how-to-add-discord-user-id-to-bot-embed-message-when-they-react-with-a-certain-r/68517251?noredirect=1#comment121124205_68517251 Thanks for helping!